Fastlane pipeline iOS: App Distribution halted because it had a problem uploading the IPA
In my iOS application I am facing the issue when trigger the pipeline for distribute the application to firebase at DEV environment.
But in production/adhoc environment it was working well and able to distribute the app to firebase distribution.
Command executed firebase_app_distribution
I am facing the below error when trigger the DEV pipeline.
App Distribution halted because it had a problem uploading the IPA.: There's been an error processing your upload.
The IPA bundle ID 'com.myapp.xxx' does not match your Firebase app's bundle ID 'com.myapp1.xxx'. Change the IPA bundle ID to com.myapp1.xxx and retry the upload.

If a Firebase app already exists for 'com.myapp.xxx', upload your IPA to that Firebase app instead.
INFO [2024-07-08 12:01:20.43]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/xxx/ios/s/fastlane/README.md'

+------------------------------------------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | cocoapods                 | 91          |
| 2    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
| 3    | gym                       | 210         |
| 4    | gym                       | 14          |
|    | firebase_app_distribution | 7           |
|                                                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

DEBUG [2024-07-08 12:01:20.64]: All plugins are up to date
ERROR [2024-07-08 12:01:20.64]: fastlane finished with errors
DEBUG [2024-07-08 12:01:20.64]: All plugins are up to date

bundler: failed to load command: fastlane 

(/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/bin/fastlane)
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane 

2.221.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in 
`user_error!': \e[31m[!] 
App Distribution halted because it had a 
problem uploading the IPA.: 

There's been an error processing your 
upload. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneError)

The IPA bundle ID 'com.myapp.xxx' does not match your 
Firebase app's bundle ID 'com.myapp1.xxx'. Change the IPAbundle ID to com.myapp1.xxx and retry the upload.> 

from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:34:in `handle'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:363:in `run'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fastlane-2.221.1/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/bin/fastlane:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:486:in `exec'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.27/libexec/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.27/libexec/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.6/x64/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>' 
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'. Finishing: Build

In the Fast file I've implemented two different lanes, one for the build and one for the distribution.
export_methods.each { |export_method|
gym(
  archive_path: archive_path,
  skip_build_archive: true,
  output_name: "xxx.ipa",
  export_method: export_method,
  build_path: ".../builds",
  output_directory: ".../builds",
  scheme: scheme,
  xcargs: '-allowProvisioningUpdates -disableAutomaticPackageResolution' + authentication_key,
  skip_package_dependencies_resolution: true
 )
case export_method
 when "ad-hoc", "development"
   firebase_app_distribution(
    # Fix Tester groups
    # Could not enable access for testers.
    firebase_cli_token: ENV["FIREBASE_TOKEN"],
    app: ENV['FIREBASE_APP_ID'],
    groups: ENV['FIREBASE_TESTER_GROUP'],
    release_notes: release_notes,
    ipa_path: ".../builds/xxx.ipa",
    debug: true
)
when "app-store"
  pilot(
    api_key: api_key,
    skip_submission: true,
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
  )
  else
   UI.message "unknonw export method #{export_method}, not 
   uploading"
  end
  }

